# Why does the Datawrapper API return code 400 to my httr request?

Tags: r, json, api, httr

I'm trying to send a dataset to the Datawrapper API. But I always get Status 400 as a response. httr is new to me and I don't know how to format my data the right way.

What am I doing wrong? Also, Is there a way to see the actual request I'm making?

```
datum <- format(Sys.Date(), "%d/%m/%Y")
datum <- "19/10/2020"
data <- read.csv("https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/csv", na.strings = "", fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM")

heute <- data %>%
        filter(dateRep == datum)
heute$Cumulative_number_for_14_days_of_COVID.19_cases_per_100000_gerundet <- round(heute$Cumulative_number_for_14_days_of_COVID.19_cases_per_100000, digits = 2) %>%
      as.numeric()
    df_heute <- cbind.data.frame(heute$countriesAndTerritories, heute$Cumulative_number_for_14_days_of_COVID.19_cases_per_100000_gerundet)
    colnames(df_heute)<- c("Region", "Zahlen")

string_heute <- paste(df_heute$Region, df_heute$Zahlen, collapse = "\n")
string_heute <- gsub(string_heute, pattern = " ", replacement = ";")

send <- paste0("{",
"title :","xxx","\n",
"data:", string_heute,
"}")%>%
  toJSON()

POST(url = 'https://api.datawrapper.de/v3/charts', 
     add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", api_token, sep = " ")),
     body = send, verbose())
```

Comment: First, the data you try to send to the server does not look like a valid JSON string to me. Are you sure that's the format you want, not something like this instead `{"title":"xxx","data":{"Region":["Afghanistan","Albania",...],"Zahlen":[2.26,97.43,...]}}`? Second, to `POST` some content "as-is", you have to add one more argument in that function: `POST(url = '...', add_headers(...), body = send, encode = "raw", verbose())`

Comment: but then how do I get my data into this format? I've tried "toJSON(paste("title:", "xxx","data:", df_heute))" but that is not the format I need...

Comment: Wrong syntax. Try this if you want to convert the data into that format I mentioned: `toJSON(list(title = "xxx", data = df_heute), dataframe = "columns", auto_unbox = TRUE)`.

Comment: thx, I'll try that today. APIs are complicated as f***.